# How to get updated Textbox value from Repeater?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, repeater

I have a `repeater` control as listed below. It has a `textbox` control.  When a `save button` is clicked, I need to get the updated text from the textbox. I have the following code; but it gives me the old value when I take the textbox text.

How can we get the updated text?

**Code Behind**

```
    protected void Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        foreach (RepeaterItem item in repReports.Items )
        {
            if (item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem )
            {

                string updatedEmail = ((TextBox)item.Controls[5]).Text;
                string originalEmail = ((HiddenField)item.Controls[7]).Value;


            }
        }
    }
```

**Control Markup**

```
  <div class="repeaterTableBorder">
                <asp:Repeater ID="repReports" runat="server">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <div id="repeaterIdentifier" class="repeaterIdentifier">
                            <div class="reportTitle">
                                <%# Eval("ReportName") + ":"%>
                                <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnLastChangeTime" runat="server" Value= '<%# ((DateTime)Eval("RecordSelectionTime")).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff tt")%>' />
                                <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnReportID" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("ReportTypeCode")%>' />
                            </div>
                            <div class="reportFrequency">
                                 <%# " Frequency - Weekly" %> 
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="reportContent">
                            <div class="repeaterLine">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmailRecipients" runat="server" class="textEdit" 
                                    Text='<%# Eval("ExistingRecipients") %>'
                                    TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
                                 <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnOriginalRecipients" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("ExistingRecipients")%>' />
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I assume that you are binding the `Repeater` to it's `DataSource` also on postbacks. You should do that only `if(!IsPostBack)`. Otherwise the values will be overwritten.

```
protected void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        // databinding code here
    }
}
```